# get path relative to executable in bash auto completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In my project, I have all executables in `$PROJECTROOT/bin/`. The main executable `$PROJECTROOT/bin/run` can load plugins with the parameter `-p`, e.g. `./bin/run -p plugin1`. All the plugins are in `$PROJECTROOT/plugins/`. I want to add auto-completion for all plugins in `$PROJECTROOT/plugins/`. Thus, I need to access the `plugins` directory relative to my binary in `bin/run` because I want to run the executable from anywhere, e.g. I might want to run `~/myproject/bin/run -p plugin1` and it should check `~/myprojects/plugins` for the list of available plugins.

If I have the path of the executable as `$EXEC`, I can just use `$(dirname $EXEC)/../plugins` to access the plugin directory. I tried `EXEC=$0`, but that doesn't work because `$0` does not refer to the executable that I want to auto-complete. Is there a way to get the path of the executable in bash's auto completion function?

My auto completion file looks as follow:

```
_run()
{
  local cur prev opts base
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

  opts="-d -p"

  case "${prev}" in
    -p)
      local available_plugins=$(ls $(dirname $0)/../plugins)
      #                                 ^^^ this doesn't work
      COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${available_plugins}" -- ${cur}) )
      return 0
      ;;
    *)
      ;;
  esac

  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
}
complete -F _run run
```

Comment: Isn't the command in `${COMP_WORDS[0]}`?

Comment: @EtanReisner, you're right! Thanks - if you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the command being completed is in `${COMP_WORDS[0]}` (the same way the word under the cursor is in `${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}`).

You can just use that to get the command being run. That won't help you however if the command is being run from the `$PATH` as the command will just be the bare name (and not contain a path for you to use) so you'll need to handle that also.